# Создать не стандартное меню для WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, bootstrap, menu

Имеется такая структура меню:

```
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav__top-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <span class="nav-link" id="thisIsUs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >about</span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="thisIsUs">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">sub1</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">sub2</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">sub3</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">sub4</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">sub5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
       </ul>
```

Некоторые пункты меню верхнего уровня являются ссылками `a`, а некоторые являются `span`, содержащие вложенный список со ссылками.

Меню подключаю так:

```
              <?php
                   $args = array(
                        'menu' => 'header-menu',
                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav nav__top-menu',
                        'container' => 'ul',                            
                    );
                    wp_nav_menu($args);    
                ?>
```

Но по умолчанию все пункты меню выводятся ссылками `а`.

Как сделать так, чтобы элемент списка `li` с классом `dropdown` содержал в себе не ссылку, а такой спан: `<span class="nav-link" id="thisIsUs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >...</span>`.

Необходима именно такая структура `html`, т.к. от этого зависит работа библиотеки для responsive menu.

Comment: http://belbiy.com/bg/wp_nav_menu-and-custom-walker-class/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашла решение [тут](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

Немного изменила:

```
if ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) {
                $item_output .= '<span' . $attributes . '>';
            } else {
                if (!empty($item->attr_title)) {
                    $pos = strpos(esc_attr($item->attr_title), 'glyphicon');
                    if (false !== $pos) {
                        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '><span class="glyphicon ' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;';
                    } else {
                        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '><i class="fa ' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;';
                    }
                } else {
                    $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
                }
            }
```